# Python Telegram bot API | ConversationHandler don't work properly

Tags: python, telegram

I am trying to make a telegram bot on python with InlineKeyboard controls, but it seems like that ConversationHandler just skipping the stages and shows only entry_points and fallbacks.
Here is my code:

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ContextTypes, ConversationHandler
import mysql.connector as sqlc

CHARACTER, DATA = range(2)
 
async def command(update : Update, context : ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Button1", callback_data="Button")]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.message.reply_text("Some Text1", reply_markup = reply_markup)

    return CHARACTER

async def button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE): 
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Button2", callback_data="Button2")]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)   
    await update.callback_query.message.edit_text(text=f"Some Text2", reply_markup = reply_markup)

    return DATA

async def second_button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Button3", callback_data="Button3")]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)   
    await update.callback_query.message.edit_text(text=f"Some Text3", reply_markup = reply_markup)
    
    return ConversationHandler.END

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application.builder().token("TOKEN").build()

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(entry_points = [CommandHandler("command", command)], states = {CHARACTER:[CommandHandler("command", command)], DATA:[CallbackQueryHandler(button)]}, fallbacks = [CallbackQueryHandler(second_button)],)
    app.add_handler(conv_handler)
    app.run_polling(poll_interval = 2)
```

[image: Just Entered Command]
[image: Clicked the Button]

I tried to check if my code is written properly, I checked with telgram-bot documentation example. It didn't helped at all. It seems like my code is identical to the working ones by structure.

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.